# SQL Server slow/slower than Python/SQL Alchemy

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy, ssms

Our team has been experiencing slow returns for our SQL queries in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. This just started recently, the slowness fluctuates seemingly randomly (doesn't correlate to when large amounts of data are being written to the DB), and now a new data point is that sending the same query using Python's Pandas and SQL alchemy library returns data much quicker.

Python:

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

database = 'database'

params = urllib.parse.quote_plus(
    'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};' +
    'SERVER=' + sqlserver + ';DATABASE=' + database + ';Trusted_Connection=yes;')
engine = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % params)

df = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM table', con=engine)
```

SQL in SMSS:

```
SELECT * FROM table
```

Both return the same data.

Comment: What type of cursor are you using? Do you get the same issue if you add a `LIMIT 10`? Are there lots of dates to parse?

Comment: @JonSG, having trouble seeing what cursor. My guess is the default one. The table takes 27 seconds with the Python method and 48 seconds in SQL Server. However if I limit it to 100, Python takes 5 seconds and SQL Server takes 2. 11 of the 136 columns are date columns.

Comment: I don't really know SSMS, but I read it supports 4 types of cursor, just wondering if trying others that the default might help. I see one of them is "firehose" and that seems promising. Really just grasping for straws as how to help.

Comment: Have you inspected the Cached Execution Plan DMVs yet? When SQL Server caches execution plans those plans are keyed on the hash of the statement as well as the client's current @@OPTIONS value. Two clients can submit exactly the same statement text but, because they have different @@OPTIONS, two plans will be constructed and cached - and may actually be doing completely different things to generate the results.

Comment: It would be pretty unusual to see different execution plans for a simple query `SELECT * FROM table` are you sure this is your *exact* query? If it is not, please show your real one, along with relevant table *and index* definitions, and please share query plans https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan

Comment: Multiple reasons why you could be seeing differences - not schema qualifying your objects can lead to separate execution plans for the default schema of each user executing that code.  Different connection options can cause separate execution plans to be generated - and, using '*' to return all 136 columns.  Not to mention network traffic - depending on where the client is sitting can impact execution times.